# Spurious space introduced by xeCJK

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk

To represent graphemes or grapheme strings I use the following command:

```
\def\grapheme#1{\ensuremath{\mathopen{<}}#1\ensuremath{\mathclose{>}}}
```

There seems to be something in `xeCJK` that inserts a blank space after the left delimiter. This does not happen with parentheses, brackets or braces, as you can see in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
\def\grapheme#1{\ensuremath{\mathopen{<}}#1\ensuremath{\mathclose{>}}}

\grapheme{{勉}}

({勉})

[{勉}]

\{{勉}\}

\end{document}
```

which gives: [image] (arrow added to show the spurious blank space).

I guess that this has to do with space systematically added when switching from any other script to CJK, which is a good thing in general, but not wanted here.

How can I deactivate this feature to avoid this space? (Of course I can add a `\kern-.15em` to make it disappear but this would mean I have to treat command `\grapheme` differently when the argument is CJK, I would prefer a global solution…)

Comment: No, the `\ensuremath` is closed before the `#1` argument, so I'm definitely not in math mode. And i can't use `\mbox` because sometimes graphemic strings need to be broken…

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was on smartphone and I've mismatched braces.

Comment: Following the duplicate: `\def\grapheme#1{\bgroup\xeCJKsetup{CJKecglue={}}\ensuremath{\mathopen{<}}#1\ensuremath{\mathclose{>}}\egroup}` seems to work.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! Could you please write an answer so that I can validate it?

Comment: @yannis now that the question is closed as a duplicate it is no longer possible to add answers - the idea is that the answer to the other question is also the answer to this question, so it will remain a comment here :) Καλά Χριστούγεννα!